# Apply a custom function on columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to do something equivalent to

```
Select x,y,z from data where f(x, Y);
```

And f is my customized function that looks into the values of specific columns in a row and returns True or False. I tried the following:

```
df = df.ix[_is_detection_in_window(df['Product'], df['CreatedDate'])== True]
```

But I get

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

I think it does not iterate over the rows. 
I also tried:

```
 i = 0
   for index, row in df.iterrows():
           if _is_detection_in_window(row['Product'], row['CreatedDate']):
                   print 'in range '
                   new_df.iloc[i] = row
                   i+= 1
   df = new_df
```

but I get :

```
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your function doesn't accept `Series`, but that can be changed using `np.vectorize`:

```
v = np.vectorize(_is_detection_in_window)
df = df.loc[v(df['Product'], df['CreatedDate'])]
```

Furthermore, you should refrain from using `.ix` which is now deprecated as of v20.

Comment: yes, my function accepts two strings, so I would like to iterate over the rows and select the rows that match the function f that is defined on specific columns. I've written my other try in my post, but it does not work.

Comment: Perfect man!, awesome, thanks. Can you also tell me what is wrong with my second solution.

Comment: @Alex Possibly an issue with your index. You might have wanted `new_df.iloc[index]` instead. Even so, if you want to filter out rows, what you're doing is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your function looks, but I assume it returns a list of bools equal to the number of rows in your df:

```
df = df.iloc[_is_detection_in_window(df['Product'], df['CreatedDate']), :]
```